# Apache Nutch NoSuchElementException with bin/nutch inject , readdb, generate options

Tags: web-scraping, nutch

I am new to Apache Nutch 2.3 and Solr. I am trying to get my first crawl working. I installed Apache Nutch and Solr as mentioned in official documentation and both are working fine. However when I did the following steps I get errors - 
bin/nutch inject examples/dmoz/  - Works correctly
(InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 2
InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering:130)

Error - $ bin/nutch generate -topN 5
GeneratorJob: starting at 2015-06-25 17:51:50
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: true
GeneratorJob: normalizing: true
GeneratorJob: topN: 5

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.TreeMap.key(TreeMap.java:1323)
at java.util.TreeMap.firstKey(TreeMap.java:290)
at org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore.execute(MemStore.java:125)
at org.apache.gora.query.impl.QueryBase.execute(QueryBase.java:73) ...
GeneratorJob: generated batch id: 1435279910-1190400607 containing 0 URLs
```

Same errors if i do - $ bin/nutch readdb -stats
Error - java.util.NoSuchElementException ... 
Statistics for WebTable:

```
jobs:   {db_stats-job_local970586387_0001={jobName=db_stats, jobID=job_local970586387_0001, counters={Map-Reduce Framework={MAP_OUTPUT_MATERIALIZED_BYTES=6, REDUCE_INPUT_RECORDS=0, SPILLED_RECORDS=0, MAP_INPUT_RECORDS=0, SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=653, MAP_OUTPUT_BYTES=0, REDUCE_SHUFFLE_BYTES=0, REDUCE_INPUT_GROUPS=0, COMBINE_OUTPUT_RECORDS=0, REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS=0, MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS=0, COMBINE_INPUT_RECORDS=0, COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES=514850816}, File Input Format Counters ={BYTES_READ=0}, File Output Format Counters ={BYTES_WRITTEN=98}, FileSystemCounters={FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=1389120, FILE_BYTES_READ=1216494}}}}
TOTAL urls: 0
```

I am also not able to use generate or crawl commands.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What datastore are you using? HBase?

Answer (score 0):

I too am new to nutch.  However, I think the problem is that you haven't configured a data store.  I got the same error, and got a bit further.  You need to follow this: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial, or this: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Cassandra.  Then, rebuild: `ant runtime`